# Laravel value in TextArea

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm getting a strange issue with Laravel and HTML's Text Areas and I can't figure out how to bypass it. Here is the code of my textarea :

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="comment">Commentaire:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment">
      @foreach ($comments as $com)
        {{$com->comment}}
      @endforeach
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

So I'm getting multiples results from my controller, and I would like to add all of them to the text box. The problem I have is indentation.

http://prntscr.com/d16tq1

The tabulations are written in the textarea. So if i delete all indentation, result is correct, but my code isn't (I can't leave a part of code like that).
Any solution to avoid the tabs in the text area ?

Comment: Put the whole *textarea* block in one line.

Comment: @itachi yes, that's what i'll do i guess, but I wanted a solution to keep my indentation. Looks like it can't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a problem with textarea's because you have tabs in your code it will also add those tabs/spaces into the HTML. So what you need to do is make the entire foreach into one line like this:

```
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment">@foreach ($comments as $com){{$com->comment}}@endforeach</textarea>
```

use HTML or CSS to style it correctly

Comment: He could also use the Collection methods. `implode($glue, $comments->pluck('comment'))` [Collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections#available-methods)

Comment: Yes, the "one line" solution works, but is really ugly x)  I guess I have no other choice tho

Answer (score 1):

In my code there was only a blank space. I resolved it as follows:

Problem:

```
<textarea id="inputDescriptionEs" class="form-control" name="description_es" rows="4" required>@isset($data){{$data->description_es}}@else @endIf</textarea>
```

The problem was with the space between @else and @endIF

Solution:

```
@isset($data)
 <textarea id="inputDescriptionEs" class="form-control" name="description_es" 
 rows="4" required>{{$data->description_es}}</textarea>

@else
<textarea id="inputDescriptionEs" class="form-control" name="description_es" rows="4" required></textarea>

@endIf
```

Answer (score 0):

change `{{$com->comment}}` to `{{trim($com->comment)}}` that should solve your problem

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Because the spaces are not in the $com->comment value, they really are on hard HTML code

Comment: trim used to remove only first and last white spaces from string.

Answer (score 0):

Use following regular expression to replace tabs from your string then it assign on textarea:

```
preg_replace('/\t/g', '',"your string")
```

Or update your scripts as followings:

```
@foreach ($comments as $com)
    {{preg_replace('/\t/g', '', $com->comment)}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: As I already said, this won't work, because spaces and tabs aren't in the $com->comment value, but in the real HTML code. In my code, if I remove all indentation, the result is ok, so no correction on the value of my chain will work.